# Examples of PM rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Def. A ring R is called a **pm ring** if each prime ideal is contained
in exactly one maximal ideal.

I asked *AI* to give some examples of pm rings. The answer is:
*Examples of PM rings in algebra include:

The ring of integers, ℤ.

The ring of polynomials with coefficients in a field, F[x].*...

But in either case $0$ is a prime  ideal that is contained
in infinitely many maximal ideals. Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably your definition should say that a pm ring is one in which every _non-zero_ prime ideal is contained in exactly one maximal...

Comment: Thank you. so Z is not mp ring with the above definition. am i right?

Comment: Well, with the definition you gave, requiring that $\{0\}$ (which is prime in a ring with no zero-divisors) to be contained in just one maximal ideal, $\mathbb Z$ would not be "pm". But with "non-zero prime...", $\mathbb Z$ would be "pm".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00927878208822703#:%7E:text=A%20pm%2Dring%20A%20is,such%20that%20aa%27%20%3D%200.), PM-rings are defined as *each prime ideal is contained in a unique maximal ideal*,(1) and examples are given. Notably $\mathbb Z$ is not there, and you can it *would* be there if valid, so I'm fairly certain this is just AI blabber.  The other example it gave is also wrong.

On the other hand, I have seen the condition *every nonzero prime is contained in a unique maximal ideal* (2) for example in the [definition of h-local domains.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1997153). Of course, they match when the ring isn't a domain...

Why on earth would you ask AI math questions? It is highly unreliable beyond asking for common definitions.  I once asked it for an example of a division ring not isomorphic to its opposite ring and it said "the quaternions, because the opposite ring of the quaternions is a commutative ring..."

Actual examples would include local rings and zero dimensional rings, and also quotients of $h$-local domains by an ideal other than zero.

Comment: True, the real problem is asking (the current state of) AI entities "delicate" math questions. They've been mostly trained to be in harmony with the (mostly vague!) threads of human pop culture, nothing tooooo delicate. :)

Comment: It just occurred to me that asking an AI about some very delicate/precise mathematical or other things (where tiny details make a huge difference) might be akin to asking a clever, well-educated-in-the-classics, well-spoken person about math... :)  The difference might be (for now) that a really smart generally-educated person would decline to offer an opinion about technical stuff... I hope! :)

Comment: @paulgarrett It's not like asking a person at all. It's an oracle of BS. It _looks_ like cleverness to us because of the (relative) quality and confident delivery. But it's harder to detect because as humans we're used to BS being malicious. This sort of non-malicious mathematically generated BS is a new thing in the human experience.  It's like a better ouiji board

Comment: Hahahaha! :) :)  Very true. In human terms, the track record of BS-ers is that most of them have some malicious component. The "random BS" thing is a bit trans-human. :)

Comment: Maybe "coffee-shop"? :)

Comment: Thank you @rschwieb . Hereafter I ask you that are HI 
(human intelligence).:)

Comment: @1400 I guess I was as bit harsh. There's no harm in asking AI... as long as you are fiercely skeptical and thoroughly vet its suggestions yourself.  That (clearly) happened to me once personally too. :)